# Symfony Form EntityType caching

Tags: symfony, caching, entity, symfony-forms, query-builder

In Symfony v3.2, I'm using a form with several EntityType fields, which have hundreds of options - and each option is a relatively big object.
Since they don't change so often, I'd like to use some Cache in Symfony, to load them once and just keep feeding the EntityType with it.

I've already cut down the size of the data that's feeding it, by pulling just the fields that I need, and then saved that into a cache.

When I pull the data from cache - I cannot feed it directly to EntityType with a `choice_list`, because it gets detached from ObjectManager, and I get an error (*"Entities passed to the choice field must be managed"*).
To re-attach it, I could use the ObjectManager->merge(), but then it means doing a call to DB for each item being re-merged and re-attached to the Manager. That beats the purpose of Caching.

What is the best way to proceed in this scenario? Just lose the EntityType completely from the Form (for speed-sensitive pages) and go with the ChoiceType (which would also include changing the logic in many parts of code)? Anything nicer than that?

So far I didn't find anything near to solution on SO or elsewhere.

Comment: What about Doctrine second level cache? See http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html for a quick reference

Comment: Tnx for this, I will look it up. I see that Symfony mentions it is "marked as experimental for now", but worth taking a look. If that possibly doesn't work, I will need to convert the biggest EntityType fields into ChoiceTypes, to be able to cache an then use plain array data.

Comment: @MassimilianoArione have you possibly ever tried or managed later to do anything with second level cache?

Comment: Of course I did. It's pretty simple

Comment: After I removed some of my unnoticed mistakes, it started working, so apparently it was not that complicated. But I would still say it's simple only if you know exactly what you're doing. I'll post my scenario here in the next days.

Comment: So how did u managed to make it work? I'm not sure how to enable second level cache in symfony...

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same question when profiling my forms. One of the problems I faced is that adding [Second level caching](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/second-level-cache.html) is very easy when using the `QueryBuilder`, but the `EntityRepository` methods don't use that cache out of the box.

The solution was actually pretty simple. Just add some cache settings to your `query_builder`. Here an [example from the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder):

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => User::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')

            //add something like this
            ->setCacheable(true)
            ->setCacheMode(Cache::MODE_NORMAL)
            ->setCacheRegion('default')

            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'username',
));
```

Don't forget to add the second level cache to your entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Cache(region="default", usage="NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE")
 */
class User
{

}
```