# Using @ParamConverter for a setter on Entity property

Tags: symfony, parameters, entity

It's pretty clear how to use the @ParamConverter in Symfony's Controllers, but I have (or would like) to use it inside an Entity's setter method (for some of the class properties). Is that even meant to work?

If that's anyhow possible, and more info is needed, the situation is like this: I have a non-simple Entity, with properties that are of various custom types. To avoid creating form field dropdowns with an EntityType on each Form (because of some caching issues, mentioned here: [Symfony Form EntityType caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185050/symfony-form-entitytype-caching)), I used the ChoiceType instead, but with ChoiceTypes the values of those properties that are selected and submitted on the form, are not converted to the proper entity type anymore (they just stay a simple int or a string as listed in the dropdown).

So, I want to convert them somehow by my self and I guessed @ParamConverter should be my best friend, but can't get it to work.
I'm trying something like this, inside of an entity class:

```
/**
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\MyEntityClass $myParam
 * @ParamConverter("myParam", class="AppBundle:MyEntityClass", options={"id" = "customIdName"})
 * @return MyEntityClass
 */
public function setMyParam(MyEntityClass $myParam = null)
{
    $this->myParam = $myParam;

    return $this;
}
```

It fails with a standard message of `Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\MyClassName", "string" given`

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Bad practice imho, you should have a look at the form events.

Comment: Tnx. Form events seemed like an overkill.. or maybe not an overkill really, but ParamConverter seemed like a nice simple solution, which would handle a problem with a couple of simple annotations. Do you feel it's wrong because of performance or code structure?
If I go with form events, then I'd need to create them in any class with similar needs (and there may be a couple of those).

Comment: But that not the use case of a param converter. Not a problem with event, an event can be used on multiple forms.

Comment: Ok. I tried to do some init in the form's onPreSet event and it does that part and init the form as it should, but when I do the handleRequest($request), after preset-ting the form, that is where it breaks. It tries to attach the value coming from $request to the property of an underlying object, with a standard setter - and then it fails. Because standard setter will just take the string value and assign it, without trying to convert it to a proper entity.  That is why I was originally trying to handle the conversion in the setter.